# if condition is not working in error response

Tags: reactjs, response

When I tried to check the condition for the response status, it is not even going inside and checking if, what should be done to compare and show the alert. FYI swal is a npm package used for alert

```
onSubmit(values) {
    this.props.signIn(values, response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            swal("Login successful", "Signed In", "success");
            this.props.history.push(`/dashboard/${response.data.user_name}`);
        } else {
            console.log("wrong password");
            swal({
                title: "Invalid Email Id or password",
                icon: "warning"
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Action.js

```
export function signIn(values, callback) {
    const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/${APP_ID}/${API_KEY}/users/login`, values).then(() => callback());

    return {
        type: LOGIN_DETAILS,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to return axios promise, try with that code

```
    onSubmit(values) {
    this.props
      .signIn(values)
      .then((response) => {
        swal("Login successful", "Signed In", "success");
          this.props.history.push(`/dashboard/${response.data.user_name}`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("ajax error");
        swal({
          title: "Invalid Email Id or password",
          icon: "warning",
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: It just works fine when I give the alert in catch.. dont need to change the action.js. So if you edited the action.js, I will be giving the verified answer

Comment: yeah that's fine

Answer (score 0):

first error is `response.status` will be **undefined** because you didn't pass response back in `callback()`

second one is if **axios.post** fail it will never call **callback()**, that mean the whole if else won't work.

To fix this you just need to change your action to this

```
export function signIn(values, callback) {
    const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/${APP_ID}/${API_KEY}/users/login`, values).then(callback).catch(callback);

    return {
        type: LOGIN_DETAILS,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

or

```
export function signIn(values, callback) {
    const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/${APP_ID}/${API_KEY}/users/login`, values).then((response) => callback(response)).catch((error) => callback(error));

    return {
        type: LOGIN_DETAILS,
        payload: request
    };
}
```